# Using Physic tab in 2.68 to make swinging linked-chain--problem with "weight" and chain-links that snap

Tags: animation, physics

How do i strengthen the bonds/material in a plain linked-loop chain, in a non-kinematic chain--ie using "hard body" setting in the physics tab!  these bonds behave strangely and break every time...  I'm attempting to replicate the tutorial listed [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/videos/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics/comment-page-1/)  one of Andrew Price's "Blender Guru" videos...

I'm trying to create a simple swinging "wrecking Ball" but setting the weights of the individual chain lengths to 2KG (24 chain lengths) and the ball on the end to 10KG doesn't work..

I'm told that scaling up the chain makes the physics work better, that "too small" objects don't behave well.

I've set everything in the scene to be "Cast Iron", and I would have thought that 2KG mass of a single link should not break, but it does, roughly into thirds, every time I hit the animation button

Does anybody have a list of "things to try" to fix this?

Comment: No need to type in all caps and I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, try rephrasing your question a bit.

Comment: If you don't want the constraints to "break", disable *Breakable* for each constraint (select them all and disable it, the right click on the check box and press *Copy To Selected*).

Comment: Andrew sets the ball mass to 10Kg and the links to 4Kg, as your chain is longer you may need to use a link mass higher than that to also support the weight of the extra links. How thick the chain links are also plays a part in their strength.